# data.table create table from rows

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to analyze a table that reports job codes used by people over the course of several  pay periods: I want to know how many times each person has used each job code.
The table lists people in the first column, and pay periods in subsequent columns -- I cannot transpose without creating new problems with names.
The table looks like this:

| people | pp1 | pp2 | pp3 | pp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | A | A | C |
| Ted | B | B | B | B |
| Alice | B | A | C | C |

My desired output looks like this:

| people | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| Ted | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Alice | 1 | 1 | 2 |

My code is as follows:

```
myDT <- data.table(
    people = c('Bob','Ted','Alice'),
    pp1 = c('A','B','B'),  
    pp2 = c('A','B','A'),  
    pp3 = c('A','B','C'),  
    pp4 = c('C','B','C')  
)

id.col=paste('pp',1:3)
myDT[ , table(as.matrix(.SD)), .SDcols = id.col, by = 1:nrow(myDT)]
```

but it's nowhere close to working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
melt(myDT, "people") |>
  dcast(people ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
#    people     A     B     C
#    <char> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  Alice     1     1     2
# 2:    Bob     3     0     1
# 3:    Ted     0     4     0
```